# How to upload emails to sharepoint document library automatically?

Tags: email, sharepoint, outlook, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I was wondering if it is possible to upload emails from outlook into sharepoint automatically. 
Is this possible with web parts or features?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to link you SharePoint with your outlook?

Regards
Rahul